# Get AWS Glue Crawler to re-visit the folder for a partition that's been deleted

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena

I have an AWS Glue crawler that is set-up to crawl new folders only. I tried to see if deleting a partition would cause it to re-visit the corresponding S3 folder, and it doesn't. Is there a way I can force a re-visit of a folder, short of changing the crawler to crawl all folders?

Comment: If you just wish to 'notice' a deleted partition, you could run `MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename`. Not sure the best way to automate it (perhaps Lambda to Athena?).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein - You're welcome to post this as an answer and I'll accept it. This is what solved my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just wish to 'notice' a deleted partition, you could run MSCK REPAIR TABLE tablename.

Not sure the best way to automate it (perhaps Lambda to Athena?).

Answer (score 1):

If your partitions are "predictable", for example date based, you could completely bypass the crawlers and use partition projection. See the docs:

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/athena/latest/ug/partition-projection.html